# Instagram Business Discovery API: retrieve single media by ID

Tags: api, facebook, instagram

Is there any way to get data for a single media obtained with business discovery? Here's my use case:

I use business API to get media from certain users.
I save all the post data, including media ID, images, etc., to build a gallery.

Once in a while, some media URLs expire, and the gallery starts to show broken images, so I need a function that refreshes the posts that have expired images via API in order to get the new media URLs.

To do that, I need to access the single media. I tried with direct media ID

```
GET /{media-id}
```

But I got

```
Unsupported get request. Object with ID '17893828628657031' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.
```

I don't have direct access to media discovered with business discovery API.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that I don't have direct access to media discovered with business discovery API.

Yes, that appears to be the case. In the endpoint documentation, in the section titled ["Getting Basic Metrics on Media"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery#getting-basic-metrics-on-media), it explicitly says:

> You can use both nested requests and field expansion to get public fields for a Business or Creator Account's media objects. **Note that this does not grant you permission to access media objects directly — performing a GET on any returned IG Media will fail due to insufficient permissions.**

So I guess you could only make the original business discovery request again - and then update your data storage with the current URLs this returns. If the account added new media since your last request, you might need to paginate through the results, to find your specific older media item IDs in there again.

Comment: It would be very useful to know what Meta classes as 'basic metrics' for media objects accessed via the business discovery endpoint. Do you have any insight as to what other metrics are available?

Comment: Here is the reference for public fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media#fields

Comment: @Sam are you talking about any actual _insight_ metrics? Then none, I suppose - insights are only available to owners.

Comment: Yes and no @CBroe – insights would be great, but specifically I want reel views,  which I think _should_ be part of the 'public' API data because views figures are available in the Instagram UI

Comment: Publicly available via UI does not mean publicly available via API in a lot of places when it comes to the Facebook Graph API - and I am guessing they are following a similar philosophy with their IG APIs.